# Docker distributed storage volume options

Tags: postgresql, docker, distributed, docker-volume

I'm trying to build a high availability PostgreSQL server across 3 servers using Docker.

The first thing that I would like to address, is to start working on a distributed docker volume but I don't know where to start since it seems like Docker by itself doesn't have this out of the box, so if someone could give some ideas on how to do this I would appreciated it very much.

Comment: I think you want postgresql replication rather than a distributed volume. If you're trying to build an HA server, you don't want just a single instance of storage.

Comment: @larsks That's what I'm trying to solve, how can I have a distributed volume across those 3 servers instead of having a single instance of storage.

Comment: I think you missed the point of my comment.  Good luck!

Comment: @larsks Ok why would you say that I want replication instead of a distributed volume?